# Error in asp.net c# code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code, this code was recommended to me by stackoverflow user on my previous post, its throwing some error

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String a = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;
        String b = DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Value.PadLeft(3, '0');      
        String c = TextBox2.Text.PadLeft(5,'0').ToString();
        String d = TextBox3.Text.ToString();
        String digit = a+ b  + c + d;
        string sql = "select * from testcase.main where reg_no =?";

try
        {
            using (OdbcConnection myConn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=testcase;User=root;Password=root;Option=3;"), 
                OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, myConn))
            {
                    myConn.Open();
                    //**
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", digit);
                    using (odbcReader MyReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        //**
                        while (MyReader.Read())
                        {
                            String f = MyReader["pet_name"].ToString();
                            String g = MyReader["res_name"].ToString();

                            Label9.Visible = true;
                            Label9.Text = f;

                            Label10.Visible = true;
                            Label10.Text = "VS";

                            //Label11.Visible = true;
                            Label11.Text = g;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            Response.Write(e1.ToString());
        }
    }
```

**the error is:**

```
Error 1 Cannot use more than one type in a for, using, fixed, or declaration statement
```

How can i resolve this error??what is the problem in declaration?

Comment: Yes i understood also but dint know the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two variables wrapped in a `using` statement:

```
using (OdbcConnection myConn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=testcase;User=root;Password=root;Option=3;"), 
                OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, myConn))
```

Separate them into two nested `using` statements.

```
using( IDisposable obj1 )
{
    using( IDisposable obj2 )
    {
         // code
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need double-indentation.

Comment: using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, myConn)) i seperated this way and now i got another error

Comment: ERRIR: The type or namespace name 'odbcReader' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @SLaks: I don't think you never 'need' indentation in C#. I think you mean that you don't need an extra *block*.

Comment: @Ishan, have you checked to see if you have the correct using directives? (as the new error suggests)

Comment: @Ishan - odbcReader is not a .Net framework class (first clue is that it starts with a lowercase letter). Perhaps you were looking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcdatareader.aspx

Comment: You need to add a reference to the DLL in your project references (HINT: Project Explorer, References folder - right click on it and browse to the dll you are using)

Comment: Thank You Tim, i was using odbcReader which is not .net class instead of OdbcDataReader

Answer (score 1):

You cannot declare variables of two different types in a single `using` statement.

You need to declare the `OleDbConnection` and `OleDbCommand` in two different `using` statements:

```
using (OdbcConnection myConn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=testcase;User=root;Password=root;Option=3;"))
using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, myConn)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you.I did that but i am getting another error  ERROR 1 The type or namespace name 'odbcReader' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried it without having both myConn and cmd in this line:

```
        using (OdbcConnection myConn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=testcase;User=root;Password=root;Option=3;"), 
            OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, myConn))
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you had some typos. Please try this:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String a = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;
    String b = DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Value.PadLeft(3, '0');      
    String c = TextBox2.Text.PadLeft(5,'0').ToString();
    String d = TextBox3.Text.ToString();
    String digit = a+ b  + c + d;
    string sql = "select * from testcase.main where reg_no =?";

    try
    {
        using (OdbcConnection myConn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=testcase;User=root;Password=root;Option=3;"))
        using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, myConn))
        {
            myConn.Open();
            //**
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", digit);
            using (OdbcDataReader MyReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                //**
                while (MyReader.Read())
                {
                    String f = MyReader["pet_name"].ToString();
                    String g = MyReader["res_name"].ToString();

                    Label9.Visible = true;
                    Label9.Text = f;

                    Label10.Visible = true;
                    Label10.Text = "VS";

                    //Label11.Visible = true;
                    Label11.Text = g;

                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e1)
    {
        Response.Write(e1.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: odbcReader is not a known type. OdbcDataReader should be. Also you can stack your using statements if nesting them is too hard to read.